# Catching a default error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, exception, try-catch, throw

I am trying to learn Swift, and wondered about Apple's expected answer to the experiment below which is provided in the **Error Handling** section of Apple's [GuidedTour](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.playground.zip) playground as follows;

> **Experiment:** Add code to throw an error inside the do block. What kind of error do you need to throw so that the error is handled by the first catch block? What about the second and third blocks?

```
enum PrinterError: ErrorType {
    case OutOfPaper
    case NoToner
    case OnFire
}

func sendToPrinter(printerName: String) throws -> String {
    if printerName == "Never Has Toner" {
        throw PrinterError.NoToner
    }
    return "Job sent"
}

do {
    let printerResponse = try sendToPrinter("Gutenberg")
    print(printerResponse)
} catch PrinterError.OnFire {
    print("I'll just put this over here, with the rest of the fire.")
} catch let printerError as PrinterError {
    print("Printer error: \(printerError).")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Below are my answers to the questions asked in this experiment, and they all seem to work...

> What kind of error do you need to throw so that the error is handled by the first catch block?

By adding **throw PrinterError.OnFire** as below;

```
do {
    throw PrinterError.OnFire
    let printerResponse = try sendToPrinter("Gutenberg")
    print(printerResponse)
} catch PrinterError.OnFire {
    print("I'll just put this over here, with the rest of the fire.")
} catch let printerError as PrinterError {
    print("Printer error: \(printerError).")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> What about the second...

By sending **"Never Has Toner"** to **sendToPrinter**.

```
do {
    let printerResponse = try sendToPrinter("Never Has Toner")
    print(printerResponse)
} catch PrinterError.OnFire {
    print("I'll just put this over here, with the rest of the fire.")
} catch let printerError as PrinterError {
    print("Printer error: \(printerError).")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> ...and third blocks?

The only way I can trigger the third block -and the expected answer in my opinion in this case- is to create a different **enum** conforming to **ErrorType** and to throw it, as below;

```
enum anotherEnum: ErrorType {
    case someCase
}

do {
    throw anotherEnum.someCase
    let printerResponse = try sendToPrinter("Gutenberg")
    print(printerResponse)
} catch PrinterError.OnFire {
    print("I'll just put this over here, with the rest of the fire.")
} catch let printerError as PrinterError {
    print("Printer error: \(printerError).")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

However, as the first sentence for this experiment starts with "*Add code to throw an error **inside the do block.***", I wondered if there was another expected answer that I was supposed to find out while staying in the **do block**.

I'm asking because I don't want to miss something else that I was expected to find out. Do you think these answers are valid from Apple's perspective?

Thank you!

Comment: Right on point, good catch :-). I meant to write "error" and not "exception", correcting right away.

Comment: I just checked again and it's there. Upon opening the playground, there is a "Next" button at the end of the code. I can navigate to the "Error Handling" section by clicking on "Next" 6 times.

Comment: Your third example is fine example of how to get caught by the third `catch` block, though you might want to stick with standard naming conventions, e.g. `enum AnotherErrorType: ErrorType { case SomeOtherError }`. Or you could throw a `NSError`. Clearly, you'd rarely have a `do`-`catch` block whose first line was a `throw`, but rather you'd generally only `throw` if some condition was met (e.g. you might have some method that checked to see if the printer was online, and if offline, throw some other error). But it looks like you've got the basic idea.

Comment: @Rob, thank you very much for checking this code and catching the error I made with the title, I appreciate it :-).

I was just trying to perform what Apple was expecting its learners to do in the quickest way possible, so yes, it seems awkward to throw on the first line, but for the heck of this example, I think it did the job.

Comment: Wow it's great to know that there are some [IT Crowd fans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO1ebXqUFDw) within Apple :)

Comment: @jtbandes there have been a LOT of references to various stuff throughout this playground. It's always fun to discover more, thanks for pointing out to that with the scene! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more practical example of that third scenario might be something like checking to see if the network was available before even bothering to  try sending something to the network printer:

```
enum NetworkError: ErrorType {
    case Unavailable
}

enum PrinterError: ErrorType {
    case OutOfPaper
    case NoToner
    case OnFire
}

func sendToPrinter(printerName: String) throws -> String {
    if printerName == "Never Has Toner" {
        throw PrinterError.NoToner
    }
    return "Job sent"
}

var networkAvailable = false     // some other process will update this when the network is available
```

Then you could do:

```
do {
    if !networkAvailable {
        throw NetworkError.Unavailable
    }

    let printerResponse = try sendToPrinter("Gutenberg")
    print(printerResponse)
} catch PrinterError.OnFire {
    print("I'll just put this over here, with the rest of the fire.")
} catch let printerError as PrinterError {
    print("Printer error: \(printerError).")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will result in the third `catch` block being caught.

Or a more realistic, Cocoa example might be:

```
do {
    let documents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
    let fileURL = documents.URLByAppendingPathComponent("document.txt")
    let contents = try String(contentsOfURL: fileURL)

    let printerResponse = try sendToPrinter(contents)
    print(printerResponse)
} catch PrinterError.OnFire {
    print("I'll just put this over here, with the rest of the fire.")
} catch let printerError as PrinterError {
    print("Printer error: \(printerError).")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Note, this isn't actually manually throwing an error, but relying upon errors thrown by `URLForDirectory` and `String(contentsOfURL:)`. But if the `document.txt` was not found in the `Documents` folder, `String(contentsOfURL:)` would throw an error which would be caught by your third `catch` block.